# python locale not working on my machine (osx 10.7.4)

Tags: python, macos, locale

Im getting this error when i try to use python locale

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 539, in setlocale
return _setlocale(category, locale)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 80, in setlocale
raise Error, '_locale emulation only supports "C" locale'
ValueError: _locale emulation only supports "C" locale
```

I have all necessary files here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES8mb.png

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `_locale` C extension for your python installation, and it'll only support the `C` locale without that.

Comment: how can i fix that ?.
python reinstall or something else ?

Comment: I suspect it'll take a re-install, yes. How did you install it to start with?

Comment: i think i followed this guide. 
http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-install-django-on-mac-osx-lion-10.7/

Comment: Indeed, your `Cellar` path hints at a homebrew installation. Personally I have no experience with that, but it looks like you need to re-install python 2.7 with the tools homebrew gives you.