# time data does not match format '%d %B %Y %H:%M'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, localization, internationalization

```
E 02:30:01.337  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~rssdeneme/1.381823925456087196/controllers/runk.py", line 34, in <module>
    pubDate = datetime.datetime.strptime((k.zaman).encode("iso-8859-9"),'%d %B %Y %H:%M'),))
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '24 Ocak 2015 00:00' does not match format '%d %B %Y %H:%M'
```

I try to scrap a web site and get rss from it. I'm having difficulties with parsing datetimes. gae works at localhost with no problem with these imports.

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append('libs/')
    reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
    import datetime
.....
pubDate = datetime.datetime.strptime((k.time).encode("iso-8859-9"),'%d %B %Y %H:%M'),))
```

but it gives this error when I deploy to gae. I think this is because it gets my locale from pc but it cant get in gae. I have to set my locale tu Turkish how can  I do that?

tried

```
from locale import LC_ALL, setlocale
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Turkish")
```

and `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ('tr_TR', 'ISO8859-9'))`
it gives

```
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\stubs.py", line 82, in fake_set_locale

    raise locale.Error('locale emulation only supports "C" locale')
```

Comment: might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124053/python-locale-not-working-on-my-machine-osx-10-7-4

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I got no problem with python27 which installed in my pc but cant get this run at gae. i guess i ll have to string.raplace all turkish months

Comment: yes might be  easier just using a dict mapping turkish to english

Comment: App Engine doesn't really support `locale`, just barely emulate a tiny subset of that very flawed API. See https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=992 -- you're better off with an ad-hoc `replace` pass on your strings to translate month names to English abbreviations.